# Why my long fuel trim readings are higher than short trim ones?

Tags: engine, p0171, vacuum-leak

My understanding of long trim vs short one is that the short trim readings will adjust the long trim after awhile right? For example my short trim readings are in the -5 to positive 7% max while the long trim will never ever drop below 10.9% and sometimes 17.2%. I was expecting the long trim to drop after seeing the short one hover around -3 to positive 5% range. I will attach images for this morning readings taken after engine is warmed up on idle.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You are right the STFT will replace the LTFT after a given amount of time. IIRC, the LTFT is the adjustment to the tune itself to compensate for fueling issues over a longer period of time. If the STFT is large for a long period of time (whether +/-), the LTFT will be adjusted accordingly. If the LTFT is at +17% and the STFT is steadily at -3%, then after a period of time the LTFT will drop to +14%, which should then move the STFT to zero. Then if the STFT needs to move to -3% again to adjust, after a period of time the LTFT would be moved to +11%. I don't know what the "time period" is for when it makes adjustments. I'm sure it's probably different per manufacturer's specifications.

It sounds like everything is doing its job, however, +10% is quite a bit of adjustment for LTFT. I believe 17% is pretty close to maxed out. I'd ensure the O2's are in good working order and the fuel system is clean (including injectors & fuel filter if equipped).

Comment: Interesting! So if the LTFT stuck at number that is higher than STFT than it is a fueling issue? Cause i was thinking to focus only on the exhaust & vacuum leak.

Comment: By "fueling issue", I mean the ECU is keeping up with what is needed to compensate, but yes, it could be caused by an exhaust &/or vacuum leak as well.